# iMessage from computer not syncing with iPhone , not being sent

Tags: macos, iphone, messages, data-synchronization, sms

I have the latest iOS on an iPhone SE and macOS Mojave on a desktop computer with Airdrop and everything (not that latter matters).

However, SMS messages sent to my iPhone do not popup and now I am trying to send a message to an iPhone user from the computer and it is just loading.

Not **popping** up on the phone as **failed to send** either.

I've literally tried everything. Verified number, synced in iCloud, paired both with Bluetooth, USB, Wi-Fi, enabled and disabled all kinds of things on phone and computer settings. macOS is freshly installed so nothing wrong with the Mac.

Is this a known problem? I am a computer engineer so please keep that in mind when it comes to proposing the obvious like turn off the phone, iMessage, Bluetooth and so forth.

Comment: sounds silly, If your time zone is set inaccurately or your clock is manually set to an inaccurate time, you will have these kinds of problems too.

Comment: Your Wi-Fi network might be blocking it, try some other networks, see if it's a proxy or a firewall issue. Also since you're here with the question, you can tone down the last part of "keep that in mind" for the obvious.